# Wrong SOAP message generated by class from WSDL.exe

Tags: c#, .net, soap, namespaces, wsdl.exe

I have two SOAP requests, of which one works and the other doesn't. The second one is created by a class generated directly from the WSDL and it seems to be wrong.

## Working

Created by soapUI 4.0.1 from the WSDL file

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
 xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:ZWmGetEpc>
         <IpLgnum>XYZ</IpLgnum>
      </urn:ZWmGetEpc>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

## Not Working

Created directly from code with a class generated by wsdl.exe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <ZWmGetEpc xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
            <IpLgnum>XYZ</IpLgnum>
        </ZWmGetEpc>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

## Error in SOAP

I determined the error in the second SOAP message: the namespace `urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style` is somehow not properly assigned to the element `ZWmGetEpc`. It should be:

```
<urn:ZWmGetEpc 
xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
        <IpLgnum>FIR</IpLgnum>
</urn:ZWmGetEpc>
```

## Question

Now why does the class generate a wrong SOAP message and more importantly how can I fix it?

Comment: Actually, the problem is `IpLgnum`, not `ZWmGetEpc`.

Comment: Did you receive any warnings from WSDL.EXE about WS-I BP-1 compliance? This may be an RPC/Encoded service, where there's disagreement about which namespace should be used for certain elements. You could try svcutil.exe instead of wsdl.exe, but I suspect that will have the same problem.